# Access denied when opening phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I am using WAMP and the icon of the wamp is green and localhost is opening but when I try to open phpmyadmin, it gives me access denied containing the below error message:

**#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Recheck your configuration settings. Are they correct? Server host, server port, username, password, database name. http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/

Comment: check if mysql server is running also

Comment: I have checked now on 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin so it works but doesn't work on localhost/phpmyadmin, do you have an idea concern to this one?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer and Apache are you running

Comment: WAMPSERVER version: 2.2 and Apache version: 2.2.22

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`:
2. Delete everything from that file and add `127.0.0.1       localhost`
3. Reboot

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked now on http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin so it works but doesn't work on http://localhost/phpmyadmin, do you have an idea concern to this one?

Comment: @AkifHussainSayyed: If your issue is solved, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If phpmyadmin launches using `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` but not when you use `localhost/phpmyadmin` then the issue is probably related to IPV4 and IPV6.

Wndows OS's have both the IPV4 and IPV6 network stack available 127.0.0.1 being IPV4

Check your HOSTS file, you should have

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1  localhost
```

The ip address `::1` is the IPV6 equivalnet to `127.0.0.1` and of course localhost is a domainname.

The browser makes an arbitrary decision to use either IPV6 (::1) or IPV4 (127.0.0.1) when it sees `localhost` as the domainname, and it is failing because your browser is using the IPV6 network but the alias for phpMyAdmin has not been configured to allow access from `::1`.

To cope with this you need to change the `wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file to tell apache that is it allowed to accept connections from either IPV4 or IPV6 networks like so

So edit `wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` and

If you have Apache 2.2.x change

```
Allow from localhost
```

To

```
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Or if you are using Apache 2.4.x use this parameter

```
Require from local
```

I assume you are probably using an older verison of WAMPServer which came with Apache 2.2.x as newer verions should already be configured to allow access from both networks, so the first option is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
I have run MYSQL on port 3333, it will change the port inside of config.inc.php file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1' 

to   

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3333'
```

It works, Fine!

Thanks!